# How do I force MS SQL Server to perform an index join?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, indexing, join-hints

I'm working on an assignment where I'm supposed to compare different join methods in SQL Server, namely hash-join, merge-join and index-join.

I'm having difficulties getting SQL Server to perform an index-join.  Can anyone show me how I can force it to use an index-join (using a join hint or similar), or just simply provide a simple query with a join on which SQL server uses the index-join method?

Comment: How did this question show up on google in 5 minutes? Wow.

Answer (score 6):

You have [Loop, hash and merge joins (BOL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173815(SQL.90).aspx) only. No index joins.

For more than you ever needed to know, [Craig Friedman's series on JOINs](http://blogs.msdn.com/craigfr/archive/2006/07/26/679319.aspx) (he's one of the team that designed the relation engine for SQL Server)

Answer (score 4):

You can have an Index hint on straight select, but I'm not sure that the same syntax is available for a join.

```
SELECT blah FROM table WITH (INDEX (index_name))
```

you could use this in a non-ansi (?) join

```
SELECT blah FROM TABLE1, TABLE2
WHERE TABLE2.ForiegnKeyID = TABLE1.ID
WITH (INDEX (index_name))
```

Join with a index hint:

```
SELECT
    ticket.ticket_id
FROM
    purchased_tickets
JOIN   ticket WITH (INDEX ( ticket_ix3))
    ON ticket.original_ticket_id = purchased_tickets.ticket_id
       AND ticket.paid_for = 1
       AND ticket.punched = 0
WHERE  purchased_tickets.seller_id = @current_user
OPTION (KEEPFIXED PLAN);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble finding such terminology in SQL server.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Join_algorithms

Are you just looking for a nested loop that uses indexes, resulting in an index seek?